# In showing $\pi_2(X, x_0) \cong \pi_2(X, x_1)$, why don't we need a reverse path?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, intuition, homotopy-theory

In the analogue proof for the fundamental group, we needed a path $\alpha$ from one base point $x_0$ to the other base point $x_1$ and then we needed the reverse path $\overline{\alpha}$ to complete the loop.
[image]

Why don't we need a reverse path for $\pi_n(X)$ when $n \ge 2$?

If we have a path from a point in $X$, say $x_0$, to a base point of the sphere, say $x_1$, it seems we should need a reverse path going from $x_1$ to $x_0$.

---

From Hatcher's book:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We *are* using the "reverse path" (or really an entire family of "rotated" versions of the path, indexed by $\partial I^n$).  Think about what Hatcher's diagram would look like in the case $n=1$.  Instead of having a big square with a smaller square inside, you would have just a big interval with a smaller interval inside.  The complement of the smaller interval consists of two little intervals; on one of those little intervals you use $\alpha$, and on the other you use $\overline{\alpha}$.

On the other hand, in the case of the square, the complement of the smaller square is an entire family of "little intervals", one for each point of $\partial I^n$ (these are the diagonal lines drawn in the picture).  On each of these little intervals, you use $\alpha$, but these intervals are parametrized according to which point of $\partial I^n$ you're at: namely, you start $\alpha$ at the edge of the outer square, and end $\alpha$ when you reach the edge of the inner square.  So on the right side of the square, for instance, you are actually parametrizing these intervals from right to left instead of from left to right, which means you're using $\alpha$ "backwards".

Comment: But, if we use $\alpha$ backwards, isn't that $\overline\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my point.

Comment: But the book implies there is no need for $\overline\alpha$. I am not understanding why for $n=1$, we explicitly use $\overline\alpha$, but for $n \ge 2$, we don't. Can you please explain this a bit further? What happened to $\overline\alpha$ in the higher dimensional cases?

Comment: There is no need to explicitly use $\overline{\alpha}$ in the case $n=1$: the higher-dimensional argument works in that case, and is exactly the same argument (just with slightly different notation).  You can either explicitly use $\overline{\alpha}$ on the right side of the interval, or you can say you are using $\alpha$ but parametrizing the right side backwards just like in the higher-dimensional case, which is the same thing.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. However, in Munkres section $52$, he shows the isomorphism between fundamental groups with different base points by defining the map $[f] \mapsto [\bar\alpha] \ast [f] \ast [\alpha]$. How come this sort of conjugation is not happening in Hatchers argument?

Comment: It's not literally a "conjugation" for $n>1$.  Instead of writing it as a composition of three parts (which only works for $n=1$), you have to draw a picture with two parts: the outer "ring" where you use different rotated versions of $\alpha$ and the inner square where you use a shrunken version of $f$.  When $n=1$, the outer "ring" is really just two disjoint intervals, and you use $\alpha$ left-to-right on one of them and you use $\alpha$ right-to-left on the other.  So for $n=1$, you can split into three parts instead of two and say you are just concatenating paths on each part.

Comment: When Hatcher writes $\gamma f$, is this a composition, i.e. $\gamma \circ f$? Are we doing $f$ first, then $\gamma$?